# How to create a File in C drive of the system where my web server (Wildfly) is running in java

Tags: java, webserver, wildfly

My war file is running inside Wildfly which is placed on location "C:/wildfly9.0.2/standalone/deployments"
My requirement is to create a File in C:/output from my code.

I am unable to go up in the hierarchy of Wildfly folder.

Is there any way to access parent folder and generate a File on required location ?

Comment: What error do you get trying to create something "higher"?  Generally you're prevented from writing anything outside of the application servers root to prevent a bug or malicious content from reading or writing to important files.

Comment: It is giving NullPointer exception

Comment: We need to see some code to help then.  NPE's are very commonly covered here but this may be a special case.  Can you post code that shows the problem and a stack trace that shows the error?